# Ubuntu 20.04 Can't Search for Folders

Tags: 20.04, search

I just upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04. When I hit the super key and type in certain key words, the search didn't return any folders, only individual files. When I did the same under 18.04, both folders and files showed up. Any idea what caused the problem? Is it because the folders are newly transferred and not indexed yet?

-=-=- EDIT-=-=-

I figured it out. It's because I transferred a giant folder from my old computer directly to ~/. Once I moved the folder to ~/Documents, search could find all the sub-directories.

Comment: I guess so, because on mine it works for folders too.

Comment: Thanks, @db429. The folders have been there four one day. Does it usually take Linux long to index folders?

Comment: well i just tested it and in my case it comes up instantly; did you have a look at  `Settings->Search` especially the settings behind the Button `search places` in the title bar?

Comment: Yes, @db429, I did look at search settings. Behind search places, the folder "Home" is turned on. The folders I expected to find are sub-directories of Home.

Comment: @db429, I just figured it out. It's because I transferred a giant folder from my old computer directly to ~/. Once I moved the folder to ~/Documents, search could find all the sub-directories. Many thanks!

Comment: glad you found a solution - that works for you